# Klicking checkbox to get discount in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm quite new to javascript and need help to firstly get value from checkbox (which should tell the code that user going to get -25%) and then calculate the price with discount. At the moment my code let's user to input number (how much is wanted) and then javascript calculates the number and outputs it to `<p id=test>...</p>`. 
I have tried different kind of codes for discount and outputting it but because of my knowledge (at least I think so) they won't work. I can't see if javascript is getting some information from checkbox or not.

PS: The most important for me is to get javascript understanding what is the value of checkbox. Calculating I guess isn't hard :)

My html code looks like this:

```
<body> 
<p style="color:green">Check the checkbox to get discount</p> 
<h2 style="display:inline;">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" value="25" />Item:</h2> LiPo Battery 3S2P 5200mAh
<p style=float:right>Quantity: 
<input type="text" id="Text" value="">
<button onclick="funktsioon()">Price</button></p><br>
Item price: <input type="hidden" id="price" value="29.30"><b>29.30</b> euro
</p>
<br>
<b><p id="test">Full price: ... euro</p></b>
<b><P id="test3">Price with discount: ... euro</p></b>
```

And javascript:

`<script> function funktsioon() { 
var price = document.getElementById("price").value; var mult = document.getElementById("Text").value;
    var fprice = (mult*price).toFixed(2).fontcolor("green");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
        "Full price: " + fprice + " euro"; 
    var disc = document.getElementById(checkbox1).value; 
...need some code here... i guess. 
document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML =
        "Price with discount: " + some_kind_of_var_i_guess? + " euro";
} </script>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the state of a checkbox with `.checked`

```
var disc = 1.0
if (document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked){
    disc = 0.25;
}
var pWithDisc = fprice * disc;
document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = "Price with discount: " + pWithDisc + " euro";
```

Comment: Still it's not outputting nothing into <p id=test3>...</p> :/
EDIT: It's outputting "NaN" now.

Comment: Use `console.log()` to find out whats going on.  For instance, put `console.log(fprice);` after the `if` checking the state of box.

Comment: Thanks for advices! :) Got it work now. Thing was that fprice had `.fontcolor` which displayed "weird" var usage for javascript. So I made another var `var sprice = mult*price` and replaced `fprice` in `var pWithDisc`